# Run a node.js server with html-website that interacts with the website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I’m new in node.js and javascript and want to learn the basics. So what I want to do is to run a server which hosts a html-website. On that html-website should be an input text field and a ‘Send’ button. Every time when I click on send, the text I wrote in the input text field should be sent to the server and printed on the console. I have tried a few things so far but nothing worked.

Here is the code for server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
function handleRequest(request, response) {
    if(request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/'){
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);
    }
}

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(3000);
```

And here is the code for the html website:
index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>text field</h1>
<input type="text" id="input1" name="input1">
<input type="submit" id="submitinput1" value="Send" onclick="sendClick()">
</body>
</html>
```

Can somebody please explain how I can ‘connect’ the text field with the server so that there is an interaction possible?

Comment: Start by reading an introductory HTML forms tutorial.

Comment: your problems are not releated to nodejs, but to the basics. please check out this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

Answer (score -1):

To simplify the creation of your website you can use express.

to install it, simply does: `npm install express --save`

--save option is to save the dependancie into your package.json

Here is the official website with introduction and documentation:

https://expressjs.com/

A few tutorials:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-deliver-html-files

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4